# How might one prove, by contradiction, that $n$ is prime if $\mathrm{gcd}((n-k),(n-2k))=1$ for for all $k$ s.t. $1\leq k\leq(n-3)/2$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, integers

How might I go about proving this by contradiction.  I came about this on my own, but I know it is known.  It's rather obvious if one looks at a binary representation of Euclid's Orchard.  Does that structure itself perhaps constitute, by way of explanation of it's construction, a visual proof?

Answer (score 1):

Let $d$ be a divisor of both $n-k,n-2k$. Then $d$ is also a divisor of $2(n-k)=2n-2k$. Finally, $d$ is also a divisor of $(2n-2k)-(n-2k)=n$

But by hypothesis, $n$ is prime, so $d=1,n$

Since $d$ is a divisor of $n-k$, either it is true that $1$ divides $k$ or $n$ divides $k$, or both.

But $n$ divides $k$ is a contradiction, because $k$ is smaller than $n$.

Thus, the only possibility remaining is $d=1$, which means the same as $\gcd ((n-k),(n-2k))=1$